# hive3 - hiveserver2 process crashes within 2minutes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

Running hiveserver2 process (v3.0.0 of hive) on ec2 (not emr), the process starts up and for the first 1min everything is ok (I can make beeline connection, create/repair/select external hive tables) but then the hiveserver2 process crashes. If I restart the process and even do nothing the hiveserver2 process crashes after 1min. When checking the logs I see messages like 'number of connections to metastore: 1','number of connections to metastore: 2','number of connections to metastore: 3' then 'could not bind to port 10000 port already in use' then end of the logs.

I made some experiments on few different ec2s (if i use hive v2.3.2 the hiveserver2 process never crashes), but if i use hive v3.0.0 it consistently crashes after a min.

Metastore db is mysql rds, hive metastore process never crashed. I can see the external hive table ddls are persisted in the mysql (ie DBS, TBLS tables).